# JS NLP: Extract time AND timezone from natural text

Tags: javascript, nlp, timezone

I have tried both chrono (https://github.com/wanasit/chrono) and WinkNLP (https://winkjs.org/), but they all ignored time zones. Sample code:

```
const winkNLP = require( 'wink-nlp' );
const its = require( 'wink-nlp/src/its.js' );
const model = require( 'wink-eng-lite-web-model' );
const nlp = winkNLP( model );

const text = `The release happened on 21 August 2020 at 4:32 pm Eastern time`;
var doc = nlp.readDoc(text);

doc.entities().filter( e => {
  if ( e.out( its.type ) === 'DATE' ) {
    console.log( e.out(), new Date( e.out() ) );
  }

  if ( e.out( its.type ) === 'TIME' ) {
    console.log( 'Time:', e.out() );
  }
});
```

The result will be: `Time: 4:32 pm` instead of the expected `Time: 4:32 pm EST`. This is the same with `4:32pm UK Time` or `4:32 pm GMT-4` or `4:32 pm New York Time`. In all of those examples, the time zone gets ignored. I understand this might require super complex NLP, but I'm wondering if some JS library can do this.

Comment: Such a library would have to be _extremely_ sensitive to the surrounding context as to not mistake US Eastern Time with Australian Eastern Time.  Or more commonly, when encountering abbreviations such as CST, IST, and others that have many different meanings depending on where used.

Answer (score 0):

Currently winkNLP is not trained to detect modifiers for TIME. Here is a workaround for you; it leverages [custom entities](https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/custom-entities.html):

```
const winkNLP = require( 'wink-nlp' );
const model = require( 'wink-eng-lite-web-model' );
const nlp = winkNLP( model );
const its = nlp.its;
const as = nlp.as;

const patterns = [
  { name: 'TIMEwithModifier', patterns: [ '[TIME] [uk|eastern|pacific] [time]' ] },
  { name: 'TIMEwithModifier', patterns: [ 'TIME new york time' ] }
];
nlp.learnCustomEntities(patterns);

const text = 'Let us meet at 5pm UK Time or at 6pm New York time. My last preference would be 3am Eastern time!';
const doc = nlp.readDoc( text );

console.log( doc.entities().out( its.detail ) );
console.log( doc.customEntities().out( its.detail ) );
```

Here is how the output should appear:
[image]

You can checkout its detailed documentation at https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/getting-started.html.